# How can I find my personal endpoint in AWS IoT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm trying to write a Java app that behaves as a Thing, publishing data in AWS. The Documentation has this code sample:

```
String clientEndpoint = "<prefix>.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com";       // replace <prefix> and <region> with your own
String clientId = "<unique client id>";                              // replace with your own client ID. Use unique client IDs for concurrent connections.
String certificateFile = "<certificate file>";                       // X.509 based certificate file
String privateKeyFile = "<private key file>";                        // PKCS#1 or PKCS#8 PEM encoded private key file

// SampleUtil.java and its dependency PrivateKeyReader.java can be copied from the sample source code.
// Alternatively, you could load key store directly from a file - see the example included in this README.
KeyStorePasswordPair pair = SampleUtil.getKeyStorePasswordPair(certificateFile, privateKeyFile);
AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, pair.keyStore, pair.keyPassword);

// optional parameters can be set before connect()
client.connect();
```

I know what clientId is and how to find my ID, but I cannot understand the  in clientEndpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the account's personal endpoint, but the Thing's endpoint.

Go to IoT Core -> Manage -> Things, select your thing -> Interact.
Its the URL under the HTTPS part. It should be in the form xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.region.amazonaws.com, where the x's should contain mainly lowercase letters, and maybe some numbers.

Comment: This is also available under the `Settings` section of IoT Core. Only one click to get there :)

Comment: Oh, never thought it could be on Settings. And if you see it from there, it also says it's the same for all Things. Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Call the [DescribeEndpoint API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/describe-endpoint.html).

In Java, this would be:

```
        AWSIot awsIotClient = AWSIotClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        DescribeEndpointRequest request = new DescribeEndpointRequest().withEndpointType("iot:Data");
        DescribeEndpointResult result = awsIotClient.describeEndpoint(request);
        String endpoint = result.getEndpointAddress();
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT console > Settings > End Point

Now You can copy your custom End Point and use whenever you want.